# Unity position of my bullet doesn't change using RayCastHit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm  trying to figure out what's wrong with my code. I'm just following the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seT5pZ7nS_I) to create a test game but with unknown reasons my code doesn't work. I follow through on the tutorial but I guess there's something that really doesn't work since the code he does is in Javascript while I do mine in C#. of course some changes in the variables. Here's my code so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ammo : MonoBehaviour {

    public float damage;
    public float spread;
    public float recoil;
    public float weight;
    public int clip_rounds;
    public int ammo;
    public Transform sparks;
    public float fire_rate;

    public shells shell = shells.AP_SHELL;
    public enum shells {HEAT, AP_SHELL}

    private int mag;
    private float fire_delay = 0.0f;


    public void FireA(){
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, Mathf.Infinity)) {
            if(hit.transform.gameObject.tag=="Player"){
                hit.transform.SendMessage("M_Damage", damage);
                sparks.position = hit.point;
            }
        }

        mag--;
    }



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        switch (shell) {
            case shells.AP_SHELL:
            if(Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time > fire_delay){
                fire_delay = Time.deltaTime + fire_rate;
                FireA();
            }
            break;
            case shells.HEAT:
            if(Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1") && Time.time > fire_delay){
                fire_delay = Time.deltaTime + fire_rate;
                FireA();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect that the RayCastHit is the one which makes my code not to work although I'm not really sure on that. I also tried changing the transform.forward into Vector3.forward and etc but still doesn't changes a thing. Hope someone can help me on this since I can't even find the logs if something was wrong with my code.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  Nothing in your code changes the position of `Ammo`.  Do you mean the sparks aren't created?  Have you done any debugging to verify the code under `if(Physics.Raycast...` is called.  Is the `hit` object tagged as a `Player`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial doesn't use braces for the inner if-statement. The assignment to `sparks.position` is independent of the tag.

```
if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, Mathf.Infinity)) {
    if(hit.transform.gameObject.tag=="Player")
        hit.transform.SendMessage("M_Damage", damage);
    sparks.position = hit.point;
}
```

It's a matter of personal style preference if you omit the braces in the case that the "if" should only apply to one statement. It may be more clearer to see where an if-statement ends, if you always use braces.

```
if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, Mathf.Infinity)) {
    if(hit.transform.gameObject.tag=="Player") {
        hit.transform.SendMessage("M_Damage", damage);
    }
    sparks.position = hit.point;
}
```

Comment: I already got it though I didn't posted the answer yet so thanks for the answer. :)